# Why am I getting this error in my code Value of type 'CategoryCell' has no member 'updateViews'

Tags: ios, swift

```
import Foundation
class DataService {
    static let instance = DataService()
        
        private let categories = [
            Category(title: "SHIRTS", imageName: "shirts.png"),
            Category(title: "HOODIES", imageName: "hoodies.png"),
            Category(title: "HATS", imageName: "hats.png"),
            Category(title: "DIGITAL", imageName: "digital.png")
        ]
    
    func getCategories() -> [Category] {
        return categories
      }
    }
```

my view has these

```
import UIKit

class CategoryCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryTitle: UILabel!
    
    func updatViews(category: Category) {
        categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: category.imageName)
        categoryTitle.text = category.title
    }

}
```

my model

```
import Foundation

struct Category {
    private(set) public var title: String
    private(set) public var imageName: String
    
    init(title: String, imageName: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.imageName = imageName
    }
}
```

And my controller

```
import UIKit

class CategoriesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        categoryTable.dataSource = self
        categoryTable.delegate = self
       
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->Int{
        return DataService.instance.getCategories().count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell") as? CategoryCell {
            let category = DataService.instance.getCategories()[indexPath.row]
            cell.updateViews(category: category)
            return cell
        } else{
            return CategoryCell()
        }
    }
    

}
```

Comment: `cell.updateViews(category: category)`, so the method is named `func updateViews(category: SomeClass)` and you have `func updatViews(category: Category)`. It's a typo error. Always let Xcode autocomplete help you in these cases to see if there a small typo mistake like that.

Comment: I tried the func updateViews(category: Category) it didn't work

Comment: You mean that you fixed the typo (missing "e") in `func updatViews(category: Category) {` ? Or that you let Xcode autocomplete help? Typing `cell.upd`, and let the suggestion?

Comment: whao! so I let Xcode complete it for me and it worked.. thank you so much

Comment: BUT you could also fix the name of your method `updatViews`=> `updateViews`, it makes more sense...

Answer (score 0):

May be the below code will be useful for you

###### Your Model

```swift
import Foundation

struct Category {
    private(set) public var title: String
    private(set) public var imageName: String
    
    init(title: String, imageName: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.imageName = imageName
    }
}
```

###### Your Data Service

```swift
import Foundation

class DataService {
    static let instance = DataService()
    
    private let categories = [
        Category(title: "SHIRTS", imageName: "shirts.png"),
        Category(title: "HOODIES", imageName: "hoodies.png"),
        Category(title: "HATS", imageName: "hats.png"),
        Category(title: "DIGITAL", imageName: "digital.png")
    ]
    
    func getCategories() -> [Category] {
        return categories
    }
}
```

###### Your TableView Cell

```swift
import UIKit

class CategoryCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryTitle: UILabel!
    
    func updateViews(category: Category) {
        categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: category.imageName)
        categoryTitle.text = category.title
    }
}
```

###### Your View Controller

```swift
import UIKit

class CategoriesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryTable: UITableView!

    var categories = [Category]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        categoryTable.dataSource = self
        categoryTable.delegate = self
        
        self.categories = DataService.instance.getCategories()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->Int{
        return self.categories.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell") as? CategoryCell ?? CategoryCell()
        let category = DataService.instance.getCategories()[indexPath.row]
        cell.updateViews(category: category)
        return cell
    }
}
```